# Error in abs__attrs.xml after adding ActionbarSherlock

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

My project worked and I put it on Git. Now I want to work on it some more after some time. I'm retrieving the project from Git. I am able to pull both, my project and the ActionbarSherlock project. Both are without error, but my project's dependency of ActionbarSherlock is not there. ActionbarSherlock project is not under the Android build target. But when I add the ActionbarSherlock project under my project's Android build target, I get errors in the abs__attrs.xml. And if I remove ActionbarSherlock project dependency from my project the errors go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder structure was getting corrupted.